# /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter; how to make python3 work again?

Tags: python

I had two versions of python installed (python - 2.7.12 and python3 - 3.5.2). After installing python 3.7.7, I wanted to make it the default of the python3 command by making a few commands. But unfortunately, the python3 command no longer works!

```
fogang@FF:~$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Oct  8 2019, 14:14:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
fogang@FF:~$ python3.7
Python 3.7.7 (default, Mar 10 2020, 17:25:08) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
fogang@FF:~$ python3
bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found : /usr/bin/python3 : mauvais interpréteur: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
fogang@FF:~$
```

Translated: "/usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No file or folder of this type"

There is my /usr/bin

```
fogang@FF:/usr/bin$ ls python*
python     python2.7-config  python3.5-config   python3.7         python3.7m-config  python3m-config  pythontex3
python2    python2-config    python3.5m         python3.7-config  python3-config     python-config
python2.7  python3.5         python3.5m-config  python3.7m        python3m           pythontex
```

Comment: What does `type python3` say?

Comment: There's no `python3` in `/usr/bin`

Comment: Put `alias python3="python3.7"` in your `.bashrc` and reload bash.

Comment: `type python3 say` Bad interpreter

Comment: @Avm-x, I want that `python3` be python3.5

Comment: With root privileges: `cd /usr/bin; ln -s python3.7 python3`.  Now `python3` is the same as `python3.7`.  You'll need to adjust when you upgrade Python in future.  Or, if you want `python3` to be synonymous with `python3.5`, change the `7` to `5` (but why?).

Comment: /usr/bin/python3 doesn't exist, so what were you expecting to happen? How did this happen? - i.e. what commands did you run specificially? What OS are you using? If you're running Ubuntu, the fix is simply `sudo ln -s python3.5 /usr/bin/python3`.

Comment: @wjandrea , it's work ! Now, when I type `import numpy` in interpreter of python3(3.5.2) it works but it's not work in interpreter of  `python3.7`. How fix them ? I use pip3

Comment: @fogang You could install `pip3.7` then use it, but probably a virtualenv will be the better choice.

Comment: @Jonathan On Ubuntu, [changing the system `python3` will break things](https://askubuntu.com/q/880188/301745).

Comment: @wjandrea: So what are you saying?  Your suggestion to use `sudo` is equivalent to what I suggested — so, is your suggestion wrong too?  Ideally, the problem wouldn't occur at all.  It could be fixed by forcibly reinstalling the appropriate Python 3 version, too, could it not?

Comment: @Jonathan Oh I mean, `/usr/bin/python3` should be a symlink pointing to the default Python binary, so reverting it with `sudo ln -s python3.5 /usr/bin/python3` is good. If you change `/usr/bin/python3`, that's when things break. And AFAIK the packaging system, APT, relies on `python3`, so you can't reinstall it easily.

Comment: @wjandrea: OK — that's fine; it's a system directory, so it shouldn't be manhandled, but when things go wrong a band-aid solution is sometimes necessary.  Knowing that the system expects to use `python3` and find Python 3.5 means that linking to 3.7 would be inappropriate.  I wonder how Python 3.7 got installed in the `/usr/bin`?  But I'm not all that concerned — it isn't my machine.

Comment: @Jonathan Yeah that got me suspicious too, like shouldn't alternate installs go in `/usr/local/bin`? But I just checked and apparently the Ubuntu devs package 3.7 and 3.8 to go in `/usr/bin`, at least on 18.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/usr/bin/python3` is missing. Based on the comments, you're using Ubuntu, so the solution is to simply reinstate it:

```
sudo ln -s python3.5 /usr/bin/python3
```

Note that [changing the system `python3` version on Ubuntu will break things](https://askubuntu.com/q/880188/301745), so the better solution is to use an [alias](https://askubuntu.com/q/320996/301745), e.g. put `alias python3="python3.7"` in your bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar error I received:

`usr/local/bin/ranger:17: /usr/local/bin/ranger: bad interpreter:`
`/usr/local/opt/python@3.10/bin/python3:` no such file or directory

I have multiple versions of python installed (3, 3.10, and 3.11 specifically). Our errors are both saying that the file expected is missing or unavailable. So I created a symlink and that fixed my issue.

`ln -s /usr/local/opt/python@3.11/bin/python3 /usr/local/opt/python@3.10/bin/python3`